# Struts 2 label-tag renders wrong

Tags: struts2

I'm using the `<s:label>`-tag from Struts 2, but it seems to render the wrong HTML code.

The two lines

```
<p><label for="for1" name="lable1">first content</label></p>
<p><s:label for="for2" name="lable2">second content</s:label></p>
```

results in

```
<p><label for="for1" name="lable1">first content</label></p>
<p>second content<label id="lable2" for="for2"></label></p>
```

Am I missing something or is this a bug? I'm using the simple theme.

Comment: What version of S2?

Comment: Version is 2.5.17